# How can I be informed when logged out by server in Meteor

Tags: meteor, server, logout

I often got message like the following when using my Meteor App:

```
09-15 22:42:52.400  3233  3233 I chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(970)] "Error logging in with token: Error: You've been logged out by the server. Please log in again. [403]", source: http://localhost:12056/packages/meteor.js?hash=9725414143125e6990547986c27b473f43c89e8b (970)
```

I think it's because the token is expired for some reason (for example when I use Accounts.setPassword to change the user's password by force on server side, I will sure get this at next login attempt)

I don't want to know how to solve this question, I want to know, if there is an event or something else I can be informed when logged out by server, because I determine whether to go "main" page or "login" page by whether Meteor.userId() has value. when logged out by server, even Meteor.userId() has value, last login state is already invalid and re-login is needed.

Comment: Never used this before, but there is on Accounts (multi server) a method [onLogout](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogout) that can trigger a function you are passing in. Does this help you?

Comment: Basicly you get a console msg if you logged out, or getting logged out 
`XHR finished loading: GET "http://xxxxxxx:3000/sockjs/info?cb=z2665g79cn"` 
I wrote a modal, to get informed about it in the HTML